# .Net, most efficient comparison

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, performance, optimization

I have 2 arrays of N objects, xs and ys.
The objects are boxed ints. There are no null elements in either arrays.
1 >= N < 50

I can compare them with the following code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    if (!xs[i].Equals(ys[i]))
    {
        return false;
    }
}

return true;
```

My question is: using .Net JIT or CLR tricks or some transformation, can I optimize this algorithm further?

Comment: 1-50 integer comparisons should take a negligible amount of time - are you sure this actually needs to be optimised? If the answer is yes, the best option is probably to optimise elsewhere to eliminate the need to do all these comparisons all the time. This code itself probably can't be optimised much, if at all.

Comment: Not boxing them to begin with would also help.

Comment: You can parallelize or even simdify it to have a stable return time and also fast enough average timing. Something like a reduction with boolean logic.

Comment: You could do something nasty with unsafe code (assuming none of these boxed ints have ever been used to lock on or otherwise cause the runtime to use the header for any bookkeeping since they should all have the same type pointer and instance data (if they're equal), but I'd strongly advise against it. As @Joey said, avoiding getting into this situation in the first place is preferred, especially if this is *actually* in a hot path for your code.

Comment: added some benchmarks for you, take them with a grain of salt though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these aren't boxed you have a few more options, also this would basically only start to pay with larger arrays.

Also as mentioned in the comments, you could use parallel. But plinq and TPL probably won't give you any positive benefit with such small arrays, and will most definitely give a lot more overhead.

```
public static unsafe bool UnsafeCompare(int[] ary1, int[] ary2)
{
   fixed (int* pAry1 = ary1, pAry2 = ary2)
   {
      var pLen = pAry1 + ary1.Length;
      for (int* p1 = pAry1, p2 = pAry2; p1 < pLen; p1++, p2++)
         if (*p1 != *p2)
            return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

or

```
[DllImport("msvcrt.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern int memcmp(IntPtr b1, IntPtr b2, IntPtr count);

public static unsafe bool UnsafeCompare2(int[] ary1, int[] ary2)
{
   fixed (int* pAry1 = ary1, pAry2 = ary2)
   {
      return memcmp((IntPtr)pAry1, (IntPtr)pAry2, (IntPtr)(ary2.Length * sizeof(int))) == 0;
   }
}
```

Anyway, if you really are after performance, I'd be getting out your benchmarker and seeing what works for you.

Just an interesting note, this is the source for memcmp (or close enough):

```
memcmp (const PTR str1, const PTR str2, size_t count)
{
  register const unsigned char *s1 = (const unsigned char*)str1;
  register const unsigned char *s2 = (const unsigned char*)str2;

  while (count-- > 0)
    {
      if (*s1++ != *s2++)
      return s1[-1] < s2[-1] ? -1 : 1;
    }
  return 0;
}
```

### Benchmarks

Take this with a grain of salt, however these tests were run a massive 100,000 times to try to tease out any subtle differences.

```
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Mode             : Release (64Bit)
Test Framework   : .NET Framework 4.7.1 (CLR 4.0.30319.42000)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Operating System : Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
Version          : 10.0.17134
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
CPU Name         : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600 CPU @ 3.40GHz
Description      : Intel64 Family 6 Model 42 Stepping 7
Cores (Threads)  : 4 (8)      : Architecture  : x64
Clock Speed      : 3401 MHz   : Bus Speed     : 100 MHz
L2Cache          : 1 MB       : L3Cache       : 8 MB
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Results**

```
--- Standard input ------------------------------------------------------------
| Value    |    Average |    Fastest |    Cycles | Garbage | Test |      Gain |
--- Scale 5 ---------------------------------------------------- Time 0.475 ---
| Unsafe   |  54.271 ns |   0.000 ns |   1.850 K | 0.000 B | Pass |   16.95 % |
| Original |  65.349 ns |   0.000 ns |   1.820 K | 0.000 B | Base |    0.00 % |
| Memcmp   | 143.527 ns |   0.000 ns |   1.977 K | 0.000 B | Pass | -119.63 % |
--- Scale 50 --------------------------------------------------- Time 0.483 ---
| Unsafe   |  78.542 ns |   0.000 ns |   1.936 K | 0.000 B | Pass |   36.69 % |
| Original | 124.064 ns |   0.000 ns |   2.038 K | 0.000 B | Base |    0.00 % |
| Memcmp   | 181.076 ns |   0.000 ns |   2.066 K | 0.000 B | Pass |  -45.95 % |
--- Scale 500 -------------------------------------------------- Time 0.620 ---
| Memcmp   | 445.434 ns | 300.000 ns |   3.044 K | 0.000 B | Pass |   44.14 % |
| Unsafe   | 501.585 ns | 300.000 ns |   3.341 K | 0.000 B | Pass |   37.10 % |
| Original | 797.435 ns | 300.000 ns |   4.291 K | 0.000 B | Base |    0.00 % |
--- Scale 5,000 ------------------------------------------------ Time 2.172 ---
| Memcmp   |   3.519 µs |   2.701 µs |  13.625 K | 0.000 B | Pass |   46.95 % |
| Unsafe   |   5.110 µs |   4.502 µs |  19.084 K | 0.000 B | Pass |   22.96 % |
| Original |   6.633 µs |   5.703 µs |  24.364 K | 0.000 B | Base |    0.00 % |
--- Scale 50,000 ---------------------------------------------- Time 25.561 ---
| Memcmp   |  52.378 µs |  35.422 µs | 180.681 K | 0.000 B | Pass |   34.55 % |
| Unsafe   |  74.634 µs |  49.832 µs | 257.216 K | 0.000 B | Pass |    6.74 % |
| Original |  80.031 µs |  62.740 µs | 274.704 K | 0.000 B | Base |    0.00 % |
--- Scale 500,000 --------------------------------------------- Time 38.306 ---
| Memcmp   | 505.916 µs | 447.289 µs |   1.726 M | 0.000 B | Pass |   37.20 % |
| Unsafe   | 662.644 µs | 590.781 µs |   2.262 M | 0.000 B | Pass |   17.75 % |
| Original | 805.634 µs | 675.736 µs |   2.748 M | 0.000 B | Base |    0.00 % |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I would guess the overhead of calling memcmp and the marshaling to do so is much slower than comparing 50 integers with plain CLR code.